# Modal Popup Extender Saving Data Causes Page Refresh

Tags: asp.net, modalpopupextender

I have a modal popup extender

```
  <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" TargetControlID="btnAddNewGuest"     BehaviorID="newGuestPopup"
        PopupControlID="pnlNewGuest" CancelControlID="btnGuestCancel"   BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
        DropShadow="false" runat="server">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

pnlNewGuest contains all textboxes for input, a checkbox and btnSave. btnSave saves data to the server by calling the btnSave_Clicked at code behind.

On Checkbox onclick following jquery is called

```
    $("#<%=checkbox1.ClientID%>").click(function () {
        if ($("#<%=checkbox1.ClientID%>").is(':checked')) {
           $('#guestdiv1 :input').attr('disabled', true);
        }
        else {
            $('#guestdiv1 :input').attr('disabled', false);
       }
    });
```

Everything is working very smooth. The problem I face when I disable the controls in modal popup screen. The screen scrolls up however data is saved successfully.

Comment: what do you mean by 'scrolls up' ?

Comment: it is in updatepanel why it should refresh

Comment: Looking at the above problem just suggest me the approach that you may follow. I have a modalpopupextender which saves the data at the backend.

Comment: it refreshes itself automatically since you probably didn't set the UpdatePanel's UpdateMode to Conditional - which means - each change you make to a control in the updatepanel will cause the updatepanel to be refreshed, and since you changed the "disabled" property - it refreshes itself

Comment: Shai, Thanks for the follow up. Actually I found the reason of the problem but still cannot find the solution. Actually the reason for the page scroll up is when we need to save any data through modal popup. The property of save button must be set to causesvalidation=false. When I did so page did not scroll up but I need the validation on save button how can I have both things.

Comment: you can trick it! use the OnClientClick property of the save button: make it call a javascript function that uses the focus() method on one of the controls that are inside the Panel you're extending with the ModalPopupExtender - even if the page will scroll - the JS method will focus the panel again, worths a try!

Comment: Shai Thanks setting updatemode to conditional worked well. and also I did validation via jquery. and set button's property causes validation=false.

Comment: great. good to hear! I've posted the answer - accept it for the common wealth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It refreshes itself automatically since you probably didn't set the UpdatePanel's UpdateMode to Conditional - which means - each change you make to a control in the updatepanel will cause the updatepanel to be refreshed, and since you changed the "disabled" property - it refreshes itself